# How can I get both widgets in my shiny code to work simultaneously?

Tags: r, shiny, widget

Currently, I am working on creating an interactive graph using shiny. My ui.R file contains two widgets, a checkbox and a selectInput:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkbox", 
                         label = h3("Education Level"), 
                         choices = c("Bachelor's Degree" = 'Bachelor', 
                                      "Master's Degree" = 'Master'
                         ),
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = "select", 
                  label = h3("Gender"),
                  choices = c("Female" = 'F', 
                              "Male" = 'M', 
                              "Both" = 'B'
                              ),
      )
```

In my server.R file, I am able to get my selectInput to successfully run. However, my checkbox is currently not working. Here is an example:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$locksley_plot <- renderPlot({

    choice_button <- input$select
    check_box <- input$checkbox

    BM <- ggplot(data = tech_salaries_bachelor) +
      geom_point(
        mapping = aes(x = Education, y = Male, color = "blue")
      ) +
      scale_color_manual(labels = c("Men"), values=c("blue")) +

      labs(
        title = "Tech Salary Gender Comparison",
        x = "Education Level",
        y = "Salary ($)"
      )

    if(choice_button == 'M' && check_box == 'Bachelor') {
      return(BM)
    }
})
}

shinyServer(server)
```

Comment: Hi, first of all, your example is not reproducible because we don't have access to your data. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example. Besides, you should add a working (but minimal) ```ui``` part, so that we just have to copy the code in your post to have a working shiny app.

Answer (score 0):

@Locksley Here is an example shiny app that uses both widgets. I'm not entirely sure what outcome you are looking for, but thought this might be helpful.

```
tech_salaries_bachelor <- data.frame(
  Education = c("Bachelor", "Bachelor", "Master", "Master", "Bachelor"),
  Salary = c(30000, 35000, 55000, 50000, 27000),
  Gender = c("F", "F", "F", "M", "M")
)

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkbox", 
                     label = h3("Education Level"), 
                     choices = c("Bachelor's Degree" = 'Bachelor', 
                                 "Master's Degree" = 'Master'
                     ),
  ),
  selectInput(inputId = "select", 
              label = h3("Gender"),
              choices = c("Female" = 'F', 
                          "Male" = 'M', 
                          "Both" = 'B'
              ),
  ),
  plotOutput("locksley_plot")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  my_data <- reactive({
    req(input$checkbox)
    tech_salaries_bachelor %>%
      filter(Education %in% input$checkbox,
             if(input$select != 'B') (Gender == input$select) else TRUE) %>%
      group_by(Education, Gender) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(Mean_Salary = mean(Salary))
  })

  output$locksley_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = my_data(), aes(x = Education, y = Mean_Salary, fill = Gender)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
      scale_fill_manual(labels = c("F" = "Female", "M" = "Male"), values=c("F" = "pink", "M" = "blue")) +
      labs(
        title = "Tech Salary Gender Comparison",
        x = "Education Level",
        y = "Average Salary ($)"
      )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```